# java insert special characters in mysql

Tags: java, spring, utf-8

I use the below java code to insert data in mysql

```
private Long insertMFPatient() {
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
                Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "insert into test(firstname, lastname) values(?,?)",
                    new String[] { "changeid" });
            ps.setString(1, "mamá");
            ps.setString(2, "test2");
            return ps;
        }
    }, keyHolder);
    return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();

}
```

On inserting text like mamá the data stored in mysql is mamÃ¡
What should I do to correct this ?
So far 
1. I have updated the table encoding type to UTF-8
2. updated the connectionstring like jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Please help

Comment: as your output indicates, the á is stored correctly as UTF-8 - in a two -byte sequence.  Please show the code you use to read/display that information - the error is most likely there.

Comment: I can see the incorrect text in database. The error is while inserting not while reading

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using below code
ps.setString(4, new String("test".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));